# Error en crystal report (Pide Parámetros Nuevamente) C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedure, crystal-reports, dataset

Tengo un pequeño problema con un reporte el cual deseo visualizar la sumatoria del rol del empleado en cuestión el incidente ocurre cuando realizo el envió de los datos y al momento de cargar el reporte en el método load me los pide nuevamente como adjunto en la imagen, cosa que al momento de implementarlo en producción no debería ocurrir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código en el método load del formulario

```
 private void FormReporteAdmMensual_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        try
        {
            String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                try
                {
                    ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                    myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SISTEMAS-PC";
                    myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "SISROL";
                    myConnectionInfo.UserID = "TECNOLOGIA";
                    myConnectionInfo.Password = "tecnologia";
                    myConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;                      
                    String filePath = @"Z:\Sisrol-Net\Reportes\ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt";
                    //Cargar el Reporte
                    rd.Load(filePath);                       
                    //Asignarle al Reporte el DataSet                    
                    rd.SetDataSource(RolAdm3Mes(fechin, fechfin,"0930159520"));
                    //Asignarle al CrystalReportViewer el ReportDocument                         
                    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
                    SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo); 

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR REPORT: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Y este es el codigo del metodo SetDBLogonReport

```
  private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            TableLogOnInfos tableLogOnInfos = crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
            foreach (TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo in tableLogOnInfos)
            {
                tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Y por ultimo el código del método RolAdm3Mes

```
  public static SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula RolAdm3Mes(DateTime fecini, DateTime fecfin, String Cedula)
    {

        SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula ds = new SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RolMensualAdmCedula", cnn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@FECHAI", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fecini.ToShortDateString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAI", fecini.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAF", fecfin.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CEDULA", Cedula);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds,"RolMensualAdmCedula");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda , indicándome que estaría realizando de manera errónea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu problema este en que le pasas los parámetros a la consulta para obtener los datos, pero no al informe.

Añada estas lineas y no te lo debería de pedir:

```
 private void FormReporteAdmMensual_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    try
    {
        String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SISTEMAS-PC";
                myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "SISROL";
                myConnectionInfo.UserID = "TECNOLOGIA";
                myConnectionInfo.Password = "tecnologia";
                myConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;                      
                String filePath = @"Z:\Sisrol-Net\Reportes\ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt";
                //Cargar el Reporte
                rd.Load(filePath);                       
                //Asignarle al Reporte el DataSet                    
                rd.SetDataSource(RolAdm3Mes(fechin, fechfin,"0930159520"));


                                    //Asignarle parametros al Informe:
                                    rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAI",fechin);
                                    rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAF",fechfin);
                                    rd.SetParameterValue("@CEDULA","0930159520");

                                    //Asignarle al CrystalReportViewer el ReportDocument                         
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
                SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo); 

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR REPORT: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Aunque tengo una duda con tu código, en el informe, a los parámetros los has llamado @FECHAI,@FECHAF, @CEDULA? con la @ delante? si te sigue pidiendo el parámetro quitale la @

Saludos

Comment: Efectivamente ese pequeño detalle era lo que me faltaba y salio sin problema alguno , te agradezco tu ayuda!